# why cout not works before getche() in VC++ 6.0?

Tags: visual-c++, cout

I want to show a message before an input :

```
cout<<"Enter a char:";
ch = getche();
```

But when running program it does not show the message and `getche()` works and after that the message is showed !!!

The whole program :

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    int ch;
    cout<<"Enter a char:";
    //cin.ignore();
    ch = getche();

    return 0;
}
```

The whole problem that, i want to do is this:

```
1- show a message 
2- enter ONLY one char 
3- do something immediately after entering the char
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `endl` soleved the problem :

```
cout<<"Enter a char:"<<endl;
ch = getche();
```